# Line terminators

Tags: c++

What are difference between:

- `\r\n` -  Line feed followed by carriage return.
- `\n`   -  Line feed.
- `\r`   -  Carriage Return.

Comment: Those are supposed to be `\ ` and not `/`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, an `\r` character moves the cursor to the beginning of the line, while an `\n` moves the cursor down one line.  However, different platforms interpret this in different ways, leading to annoying compatibility issues, especially between Windows and UNIX.  This is because Windows requires an `\r\n` to move down one line and move the cursor to the start of the line, whereas on UNIX a single `\n` suffices.

Also, obligatory Jeff Atwood link: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/01/the-great-newline-schism.html

Comment: Note the C++ tag in there. C defines in the standard that for dealing with text files (and I think output too) the standard library must translate the platform-specific line terminator into `\n` (and back again).

Answer (score 3):

They are the line terminator used by different systems:

- \r\n = Windows
- \n = UNIX and Mac OS X
- \r = Old Mac

You should use `std::endl` to abstract it, if you want to write one out to a file:

```
std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
```

Comment: `std::endl` doesn't abstract anything, per se. It just outputs `'\n'` and flushes the stream. The output and input of `'\n'` as text, though, is abstracted. (Again, conceptually.)

Comment: Side note: CRLF is also used by nearly all text-based network protocols, such as HTTP and was also the default on teletypes back in ancient times (followed by possibly several NULs to wait for the head to return to the start of the line). Terminal emulators probably still cater for that behavior nowadays. Using only LF has a history in the first Unix systems for implementation simplicity and has spread from there. Originally, however, CRLF made much more sense.

Comment: std::endl doesn't actually abstract away kind of platform-specific newline behavior. The standard says it is exactly equivalent to s.put(s.widen(’\n’)) followed by s.flush() -- s is the stream in question -- so you actually shouldn't use std::endl unless you intended the stream to be flushed. EDIT: Gman totally beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

### Historical info

The terminology comes from typewriters. Back in the day, when people used typewriters to write, when you got to the end of a line you'd press a key on the typewriter that would mechanically return the carriage to the left side of the page and feed the page up a line. The terminology was adopted by computers and represented as the ascii control codes `0xa`, for the linefeed, and `0xd` for the carriage return. Different operating systems use them differently, which leads to problems when editing a text file written on a Unix machine on a Windows machine and vice-versa.

### Pragmatic info

On Unix based machines in text files a newline is represented by the linefeed character, 0xa. On Windows both a linefeed and carriage return are used. For example when you write some code on Linux that has the following in it where the file was opened in text mode:

```
fprintf(f, "\n");
```

the underlying runtime will insert only a linefeed character `0xa` to the file. On Windows it will translate the `\n` and insert `0xd0xa`. Same code but different results depending on the operating system used. However this changes if the file is opened in binary mode on Windows. In this case the insertion is done literally and only a linefeed character is inserted. This means that the sequence you asked about `\r\n` will have a different representation on Windows if output to a binary or text stream. In the case of it being a text stream you'll see the following in the file: `0xd0xd0xa`. If the file was in binary mode then you'll see: `0xd0xa`.

Because of the differences in how operating systems represent newlines in text files text editors have had to evolve to deal with them, although some, like Notepad, still don't know what to do. So in general if you're working on Windows and you're given a text file that was originally written on a Unix machine it's not a good idea to edit it in Notepad because it will insert the Windows style carriage return linefeed (0xd0xa) into the file when you really want a 0xa. This can cause problems for programs running on old Unix machines that read text files as input.

Answer (score 0):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Answer (score 0):

Different operating systems have different conventions; Windows uses \r\n, Mac uses \r, and UNIX uses \n.

Comment: The older Macintosh OS's use `\r`, but Mac OS X is UNIX and uses `\n`

Answer (score 0):

1. `\r`

   This sends the cursor to the beginning column of the display
2. `\n`

   This moves the cursor to the new line of the display, but the cursor stays in the same column as the previous line.
3. `\r\n`

   Combine 1 and 2. The cursor is moved to the new line, and it is also moved to the first column of the display.

Some compilers prints both a new line and carriage return when you specify only `\n`.